# jQuery UI Tabs and cache parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

As I can see in the example http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html, the component is sometimes getting the tab 3 content when I click on that tab. If you click two o more tabs and go back to 3 sometimes you will see how again it takes some time to get the content.

To reproduce this behavior click:

1. tab 3 - let it load
2. tab 2
3. tab 3 - it is already load
4. tab 1
5. tab 3 - now is loading again

In the code it's not using `cache:false` in the `ajaxOptions`, so the content should be cached, why it's not happening?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [main page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) that this demo comes from, you'll notice this comment:

> Tabs 3 and 4 demonstrate slow-loading
>   and broken AJAX tabs, and how to
>   handle serverside errors in those
>   cases. Note: These two require a
>   webserver to interpret PHP. They won't
>   work from the filesystem.

For the purposes of the demonstration, they broke tabs 3 and 4 (in different ways) so a user can see how to handle Ajax errors. Take a look at the source code on the page I linked to above to understand what they are doing to break it.

Also, if you scroll down the page a little more and look at the options, you'll notice that, by default, the cache option is false. So, if the option is not set, then the tab WILL NOT cache because it is automatically false.

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, the help says : "Note that to prevent the actual Ajax requests from being cached by the browser you need to provide an extra cache: false flag to ajaxOptions.", but there is not such a flag in the example code.

Comment: @vtortola - It is two separate sets of options. The 'cache' option (by itself) is about caching the tab. The 'ajaxOptions' is another set of options which comes from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. Two separate things.